# Check if process is hung via bat file

Tags: windows

So we are running a Pandora on a specific pc to feed music to our phone lines. Every so often the program times out  with "Are you still listening" or " Cant connect to the internet". In both instances all we need to do is to click the radio button and it resumes fine. The problem is as it only feeds the phone lines we never know when it has hung.

Currently I am closing and restarting Pandora thru a task at timed intervals. But as those conditions happen randomly as far as I can tell I still end up with no music for 1/2 to 45 min.

However in both instances when that occurs the Processor and memory usage is "0%". So what i think I can  do is check to see if the Memory and processor usage both = 0 and if so I can then close and restart the applet.

I have tried several power-shell and bat scripts but I have not been successful.
Can anyone assist?

Thanks
-EDS

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because sounds like it is about circumventing business licensing.

Comment: Business support should be directed here: https://pandora.moodmedia.com/faq

Answer (score 0):

It is not circumventing business licensing. We are a paid subscriber.